# C# Using Property of TextBox from Form2

Tags: c#, object, components

In C#, ım developıng an applıcatıon, but ı am gettıng some errors
ı got two form ın my project, form1 and form2.
but when ı want to call any object property from Form2, ıt doesnt be shown up and called. How can ı do thıs? I tried to do, but dıdn't happen

There ıs a textbox on Form2 and ı want to use ıts property from Form1

the code below ıs as ı want ıt to be...

```
Messagebox.Show(Form2.textBox1.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: do you have an instance of Form2 that is used on Form1?

Comment: Pass textbox content as parameter in constructor of your form.

Comment: That shouldn't even compile, since the textbox isn't static (at least I hope it's not; it shouldn't be).  It also really shouldn't be public either; you should add a property that just exposes the text.

Comment: @kostasch. `Form2` is probably the child form, not the parent form, so he's the one creating the instance; he just needs to hold onto it.

Comment: what should i do exactly, either?

Comment: Do you have an instance of `Form2`? Yes, where? What's it called? This is easy, providing you have an instance of `Form2`.

Comment: @Servy You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `Form1` really shouldn't know anything about the internal controls of `Form2`.  The textbox shouldn't be public at all.  Instead create a property on `Form2` that exposes the information that you need:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    private Textbox textbox1;

    public string SomeText //TODO replace with meaningful name
    {
        get { return textbox1.Text; }
    }
}
```

Next, at some point you're presumably creating an instance of your form to show it.  You can access the property through that instance:

```
Form2 childForm = new Form2();

childForm.ShowDialog();

MessageBox.Show(childForm.SomeText);
```

In some situations you may also need to store the instance of `Form2` as an instance field of `Form1` rather than just a local variable:

```
private Form2 childForm = new Form2();

private void SomeMethod()
{
    childForm.Show();
}

private void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    MessageBox.Show(childForm.SomeText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
       form 1

```
   public string _parameter;
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

     }

    public void form2_show_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       form2 frm = new form2();
       frm.ShowDialog();
        _parameter = frm.parameter;
     }

  form2

   public string parameter;
   public void form1_show_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       parameter = textBox1.Text;
       this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
     }
```